# Call a child component function from parent component in Angular 1.5

Tags: angularjs

In my parent component's template, there is a nested component.

```
<div class="inner" ng-show="!vm.loading">
    <div class="info-panel">
        <h3 id="basePrice">Current Cost</h3>
        <p>
            <small>
                <a href role="button" data-toggle="modal" ng-click="vm.openCostsModal()">See Details</a>
            </small>
        </p>
    </div>
    ......
    ......
    <pricingcalculation></pricingcalculation>
```

This `<pricingcalculation></pricingcalculation>` is the nested component.
And it's definition looks like :

```
(function () {
    "use strict";
    angular.module("app")
        .component("pricingcalculation", {
            transclude: true,
            templateUrl: "/static/angtemplates/pricing-calculation.html",
            controllerAs: "vm",
            controller: ["$rootRouter", function ($rootRouter) {
                var vm = this;
                vm.openCostsModal = function () {
                    vm.costItems = [];
                    vm.projectedCostItems = [];
                    vm.totalOfCostItems = 0;
                    .....
                    .....
```

So on that `See Details` button click **which is defined on parent's template**

I want the **child component's function openCostsModal()** to be called.

How to do that ?

Comment: you can call parent function from child, but you cant call child component function from parent, that is upto my knowledge

Comment: @WasifKhan Makes sense. And, that's valid too. But there must be a way. What about events?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use `$broadcast` in your parent to broadcast an event and use `$on`in your child to listen to it.

Like so :

In parent :

```
$scope.$broadcast("someEvent");
```

In child :

```
$scope.$on("someEvent",function(){
  //do stuff here
});
```